# What is the outp() counterpart in gcc compiler?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, parallel-port

In my School my project is to make a simple program that controls the LED lights

my professor said that outp() is in the conio.h, and I know that conio.h is not a standard one.

example of outp()

```
//assume that port to be used is 0x378
outp(0x378,1); //making the first LED light
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The LED lights of what? On what platform?

Comment: I mean connecting a LED light into the parallel port of my computer.

Comment: Which OS are you using - you will need OS specific headers/calls all of which are not standard C

Comment: See the part about `ioperm` and `outb` here: http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/parallel_output.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to write to a parallel port depends on the OS, not the compiler. In Linux, you'd open the appropriate device file for your parallel port, which is `/dev/lp1` on PC hardware for port 0x0378.

Then, interpreting the [MS docs for `_outp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/733szwah.aspx), I guess you want to write a single byte with the value 1 to the parallel port. That's just

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/lp1", "wb");
// check for errors, including permission denied
putc(1, fp);
```

Comment: 1 there is the pin number. 1 is suppose to be pin 1

Comment: @nmepntgrm: if what your `outp` function does does not match with the MS documentation, then you ask its author how it's implemented.

Comment: it matched thank you. Now I just need to read some documentations.

Comment: Try `man 4 lp` on the command line to see how the `/dev/lp*` files work; the rest is just standard C.

Comment: It is more likely that `/dev/lp0` will correspond to port `0x378`.

Comment: "The minor numbers correspond to the printer port base addresses 0x03bc, 0x0378 and 0x0278" - `lp(4)`. I assume that means "respectively".

Answer (score 3):

You can do this from user space in Linux by writing to `/dev/port` as long as you have write permissions to `/dev/port` (root or some user with write permissions).  You can do it in the shell with:

```
echo -en '\001' | dd of=/dev/port bs=1 count=1 skip=888
```

(note that 888 decimal is 378 hex).  I once wrote a working parallel port driver for Linux entirely in shell script this way.  (It was rather slow, though!)

You can do this in C in Linux like so:

```
f = open("/dev/port", O_WRONLY);
lseek(f, 0x378, SEEK_SET);
write(f, "\01", 1);
```

Obviously, add `#include` and error handling.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up two things. A compiler makes programs for an OS. Your school project made a program for DOS. `outp(0x378,1);` is essentially a DOS function. It writes to the parallel port. Other operating systems use other commands.

GCC is a compiler which targets multiple Operating Systems. On each OS, GCC will be able to use header files particular top that system.

It's usually going to be a bit more complex. DOS runs one program at a time, so there's no contention for port `0x378`. About every other OS runs far more programs concurrently, so you first have to figure out who gets it.

Comment: outp() functions worked on the first 32-bit Windows versions (98/95( too. On NT, 2000 and later versions of Windows they banned direct memory access entirely. http://www.beyondlogic.org/ is an excellent site for anyone interested in these kind of things and old port hardware. For example they have a driver that makes it possible to use outp() on later Windows versions up to XP. Been quite a while since I tried it out, but it worked nicely. I made a christmas light bling-bling LED show from my parallell port with that, on a XP machine.